# Why can't my array variable be checked correctly for values?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

So I have been working on a way to view a list of an employees and have employee options i.e buttons next to them to have it do an action in the database, but when I was making a promote to manager button It was supposed to disappear if that employee was already a manager but it only takes the first index of $managers, why won't it take all

```
<?php if(!in_array($row['employee_id'], $managers)) { ?>
<?php echo form_open('manager_controller/employee_promote', $class); ?>
<input type="button" name="promote" value="Promote" class="btn btn-success" onclick="form.submit()">&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>">&nbsp;
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Here's a print_r of `$managers`:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array
    ( 
        [employee_id] => 723 
    ) 
    [1] => Array
    ( 
        [employee_id] => 2199 
    ) 
)
```

The code for how I get the $managers array.

```
//Sets which fields I am going to take
$this->db->select('employee_id, ssn, first_name, last_name, department, title, status');

//Sets which table it is going to get the fields
$query = $this->db->get('employees');

//Uses codeigniter's result_array function to convert the the object to an array
$results = $query->result_array();

//Returns the variable to my controller so I can access it in my view.
return $results;
```

Comment: Why do you open, then close a php call right away?

Comment: What do you mean? @ElefantPhace

Comment: If it's all php, the put all of it between one set of php tags, is what ElephantPhace means.

Comment: The bad style is adding the closing brackets (`?>`) to each line.

Comment: aside from the bad styling, can anyone help me with the problem at hand?

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this? @Placeholders_in_use

Comment: Yes, you ask a question by writing it in complete English.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are not checking if each of the employee is a manager ????

Comment: @Cesarg219 you still need help?

Comment: Yes I still need help, I have not been able to find the answer with my own research

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the array.

```
foreach($managers as $manager)
    if($row['employee_id'] != $manager['employee_id']) {
```

Comment: i dont know codeigneter but if you want to make this work, see the loop in my edit

Comment: this actually put the button their twice if they were in managers so when i tried to flip it it only put promote buttons next the the people who were already promoted

Comment: Are you sure , you change $managers to $manager in your if statment?? See my edit

Comment: `foreach($managers as $manager)
        if($row['employee_id'] != $manager['employee_id']) { `

Comment: Does it help to note that when there is only one manager the way you wrote works fine but if there is more, it just adds the button twice to people who are managers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53892/discussion-between-cesarg219-and-meda)

Comment: @Cesarg219 break out of the loop
`break;` when condition is met